# Is there a way to disconnect an event added by dojoAttachEvent

Tags: dojo

I have a dojo widget which uses a a custom-library code having a link like this in its template.

```
<a href="#" dojoAttachEvent="onclick:_goBack" dojoAttachPoint="backButton">Go Back</a>
```

I need to find a way to disconnect this event from my widget. The only way i know how an event can be disconnected is, using a

```
dojo.disconnect(handle)
```

I could use this if I had the event connected using *dojo,connect()* which returns me the handle.
However with *dojoAttachEvent* i don't have the event handle hence no way to disconnect it.

Note :
Changing this html is not an option for me, since this an external library i am using.
Also, I am not looking for a solution to disconnect all events.

**CODE:**

**otherWidget.js:**

```
dojo.provide("otherWidget");
dojo.declare("otherWidget", [], {
    templateString : dojo.cache("otherWidget","templates/otherWidget.html"),
    _goBack: function(){        
        this.destroyWidgetAndRedirect();
    },
    destroyWidgetAndRedirect: function(){       
        //Code to destory and redirect.
    },
});
```

**otherWidget.html:**

```
<div>
<a href="#" dojoAttachEvent="onclick:_goBack" dojoAttachPoint="backButton">Go Back</a>
<!-- Other Widget related code -->
...
</div>
```

**myWidget.js:**

```
dojo.provide("myWidget");
dojo.require("otherWidget");
dojo.declare("myWidget", [], {
    templateString : dojo.cache("myWidget","templates/myWidget.html"),
    this.otherWidget = new otherWidget({}, dojo.byId('otherWidgetContainer'));
});
```

**myWidget.html:**

```
<div>
<div id="otherWidgetContainer"></div>
<!-- My Widget related code -->
...
</div>
```

Any thoughts.. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to achieve ? Prevent the default onClick event to execute ? I think you should use the _goBack extension point through dojo/method if that is the case. It will have the event as its first argument, and you can use evt.preventDefault() in the beginning of your overriding code... See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#creating-extension-points

Comment: Hi Philippe, Thanks for your reply. Yes, my final motive is to prevent the default onClick event. Not sure if i understood correctly, but in the extension point example, I would have to modify my library code right for it to call the  onClick? Also, using this, even if i add evt.preventDefault in onClick function, _goBack and _onClick will still execute before onClick(as per example in the link). Basically my query is now where do i write the override code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension points can be used directly on your html, or in javascript. Suppose the widget you are using is called 'my.custom.dojowidget', and that it has an onClick extension point. I will show here the declarative way, in your html. Try this :

```
<div data-dojo-type="my.custom.widget">
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args"evt">
         dojo.stopEvent(evt);
         console.debug("did this work ?");
    </script>
</div>
```

Now this depends on the existence of the extension point... if you can't still do what you want, please post the relevant parts of your widget's code.

So... based on the sample code you posted in your edit, I think you should do the following :

```
<div data-dojo-type="otherWidget">
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="destroyWidgetAndRedirect" data-dojo-args="evt">
        dojo.stopEvent(evt);
        // do whatever custom code you want here...
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: The onClick that i want to prevent is on an anchor tag is a small part of the widget i am using. This code is preventing the onClick on the whole widget right..?

Comment: Right... can you post the relevant parts of the code of your custom widget here (the one that uses the "other" widget) ? It's a bit hard to shoot in the dark like this...

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly... let me know if it works as I couldn't test it.

Comment: I think i understand what you are trying to do. The code is basically overriding the destroyWidgetAndRedirect method. Programmatically written would look like this (m not too comfortable with the declarative style :)).. this.otherWidget.destroyWidgetAndRedirect = function(evt){dojo.stopEvent(evt);} and this does solve the problem. :) 
thanks for all the help!